# Sourcing a spacer / rectangular washer to prevent rotation of a carriage bolt in a round hole?

Tags: bolts, hardware, fastener

While installing a Curt trailer hitch, I lost one of the provided carriage bolts and what they call a spacer inside a frame tube. After lots of time spent trying to retrieve the bolt, I've decided to just try again with a replacement, but I'm having a heck of a time finding a replacement 'spacer'.

The hardware in question is pictured below:

[image]

The spacer is the black trapezoidal shaped piece. It's the thickness of a thick washer; its purpose is to prevent the bolt from rotating by bracing against the inside of the frame tube. Here is a schematic:

[image]

Finding a 7/16" carriage bolt was harder than I expected but not really a problem. But I have had a real heck of a time finding a spacer, or anything equivalent.

It seems like it may be called a 'block spacer' or just a rectangular washer, but my local hardware stores have nothing and even googling has been futile. I'm looking for either a source for hardware like this (to fit a 7/16" carriage bolt), or alternately, a different solution for preventing the rotation of a bolt whose head is inaccessible. Thanks!

Comment: I answered my question on sourcing below, but I'd still be interested in alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I would just call Curt customer service and request a replacement part. They should be able to get an exact replacement, and they might even provide it for free or low cost. Call (877) 287-8634 or the number in the installation manual.

Comment: aww shoot this is so straightforward that I hadn't even thought of it. Good idea!

Answer (score 0):

A usual, I found some right after asking the question. They are available here: https://www.reesehitches.com/products/Block_Plate_Spacers___6_pack,BPK-25120S716SQ